# Unexpected behaviour of sticky div inside fixed div on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a side menu that is sticky with the screen. When opening a lightbox that prevents scroll by setting body to `position: fixed;` the side navigation disappears. This only seems to happen in Firefox.

The issue as I understand comes from the `top: -600px;` value that is used to keep the user on the same position on the page when preventing scroll (`-600px` in this case is just for the example, in my code the value is generated with JS).

[CodePen to illustrate the problem.](https://codepen.io/CheeseBisqt/pen/zYmexxV)

I created the CodePen to try to isolate the issue, when realising that the issue is created by the `top: -600px` I tried to find a workaround for it. As this is used to keep the user on the same position of the page it needs to be there.

I tried to use `transform` to achieve the same effect but did not find a suitable solution.

Comment: Please note that a proper [mre] of your issue should be contained _directly_ in your question; do not just present the whole problem on an external platform (where it could change, or disappear from, at any point, leaving this question without context for future readers.)

Comment: In your `.isFixed` declaration remove `top: -600px;`. Then, add a new declaration `#container.isFixed > #sticky { position: fixed; }`. Does this fit your needs? https://jsfiddle.net/p7Lnucas/1/

Comment: @Ferris This makes it so the view is scrolled to the top which is undesired